# Encryption at rest for RocksDB

Tags: encryption, nosql, rocksdb

I am exploring options to implement encryption at rest for RocksDB data which I am using in one application (that is, I don't have to store the key in the data, I can calculate it in runtime). Ideally, it should be DES.

Are there easy plugins or libraries specifically for RocksDB, or I will have to improvise?

Comment: DES's key space is brute forceable easily.  Don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @LukePark, but I am trying to conform to standards. If they decided DES is good for them, I'm fine with that. Any advice on the question itself?

Comment: If they decided DES is good for them, it should probably be raising some red flags to you.  The question itself, nope, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that I know of. In terms of implementation you have a few options:

1. Handle the encryption in your app. Rocks doesn't care what you store in it, just that keys are comparable. So you just need to design a sensible key encoding.
2. You could use the StackableDB feature of Rocks to implement something between your app and Rocks to handle the encryption. You would still have to design a key encoding for your data.
3. Look at how compression is implemented in Rocks try to implement something at that level if appropriate

Comment: Seems to be at most: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/commit/51778612c9cf4cb842eed10f270ec0ed29ff22f1